# Importing files from Windows to Linux

Tags: remote, file-copy

I would like to copy a CSV file from a Windows environment to a Linux environment. Both environments communicate through a terminal emulator called SecureCrt.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly is the problem that you can't solve? Do you get any errors when you use `SecureCrt`? If so what do the errors say?

Comment: Are these 'environments' on the same machine? Different servers? Can you use `cp`?

Comment: If you can connect via secureCRT, you have an `ssh` connection. If you can `ssh` you can use `sftp`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Home-page of SecureCRT](http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/) this is already built in:

"Transfer files between network devices with SFTP, Xmodem, Ymodem, Zmodem, or Kermit. A built-in TFTP server provides additional file transfer flexibility."

So use your Windows-session to copy the file to your client and then copy the file from your client to your Linux-session. According to the above you can do this with a tftp-client on both sides.

Comment: That works perfectly. Can I copy a file from windows to a Linux directory while i am at the Linux prompt? If so, How?